# Android how to change the edittext box textcolorhighlight for my customized edittext box?

Tags: android, css, xml, custom-controls, android-edittext

I have changed "android:textColorHighlight" in my theme definition but highlight stays red.

```
custom style below style.xml
 <style name= "DesertStyleEditText" parent="@android:style/Widget.EditText">
        <item name="android:background">@drawable/textview_rounded_edges</item><!-- #5f4427 -->
        <item name="android:textStyle">normal</item>
        <item name="android:textColor">#EFD9CC</item>
        <item name ="android:textColorHighlight">#DDC4B0</item>
    </style>
```

textview_rounded_edges.xml below

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
            <corners android:radius="3dip" />
            <stroke android:width="2dip" android:color="#80B47E5A" /> 
            <!-- android:color=#CC83776b"@android:color/transparent"-->
            <padding android:left="0dp" android:top="0dp" android:right="0dp" android:bottom="0dp" /> 
            <solid android:color="#815940"/><!-- #5f4427"-->
</shape>
```

Comment: Visit this site http://android-holo-colors.com/.Here you can download customized theme for EditText view.

Comment: @logu thank you but I want to do it myself. And secondly that link didnt work.

Comment: Use this link http://android-holo-colors.com/